# Visual studio 2010 database explorer sql query clears table

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've created a database in visual studio 2010 in the following way: Data->Add new datasource->Database->Entity Data Model.

Now, in my wpf app I can load and save data successfully, when closing the
app and opening again the data will still be there, but as soon as I try
retrieve the table data in Visual Studio's Database explorer it returns
an empty table, and running the application after that also returns no data.

It is as if using database explore to query data clears it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Anderson seem to explain what is going on, here:

http://www.itwriting.com/blog/689-where-is-your-sql-server-ce-database.html